# How do I change my css so that it renders the same on Safari and Chrome?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I recently designed a website with html, css, and javascript and i'm having issues with the rendering on different browsers. It seems to work fine on Chrome but everything looks off and is spaced weirdly on Safari. I've tried used normalize.css to make it better but nothing works. What do I need to do to make it good on Safari as well?

The main issues occur with columns when I use bootstrap. If I divide the row into 3 columns, it'll display correctly on Chrome but will be 2 columns and 1 overlapped on another row in Safari. How do I fix this?

`index.html`

```
<div class="panel">
    <div id="panel-title" class="panel-title text-center">PANEL TITLE</div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row more-info">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <img class="icon-images" src="img/image1.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <img class="icon-images" src="img/image2.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <img class="icon-images" src="img/image3.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`style.css`

```
.panel {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background: url("img/howitworksbg.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

# panel-title {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f5ce8a, #eb9c14);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding: 0;
}

.more-info {
    padding: 0 150px 0 150px;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post a [mcve] in your question so that we can see the issues

Comment: @j08691, i've added the example

Comment: yes, I'm using v3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Since some browsers have different screen sizes, things on your website will place differently based on each browsers screen size. Therefore, you can use

```css
@media screen and(max-width: 500px;){
}
```

For whatever screen size you want items on your screen to place differently.

Comment: that's true, i do have them on the site and it is responsive with a bunch of sizes when i test with my google console. however when opened with safari, it's a mess. i think this is a browser issue rather than size itself.